# Автоматическое создание файла в папке

Tags: php

Здравствуйте.
Делаю загрузку файлов на сервер.
Если пользователь хочет загрузить файл а папки для хранения файла на сервере нету, то она создается автоматически, с помощью кода:

```
$direct = dirname(__FILE__)."/newmp3/";
@mkdir($direct, 0777);
```

Мне нужно чтобы в каждой папке, которая создается автоматически, появлялся сразу же файл **.htaccess** , с моим кодом. в нем я пропишу отключение обработки скриптов

Comment: А почему не сделать **один** .htaccess в родительской папке? А еще лучше — в конфиге самого Apache в директиве <Direcory>.

Comment: @artoodetoo потому что для каждого пользователя создается отдельная папка

Comment: Содержимое .htaccess у всех одинаковое?

Comment: @artoodetoo да, одинаковое

Comment: Ну тогда один конфиг на всех должен подойти.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$direct = dirname(**FILE**)."/newmp300/";
@mkdir($direct, 0777);
if (!file_exists(''.$direct.'/.htaccess'))file_put_contents(''.$direct.'/.htaccess', 'RULES');